# How to pass an iterator index value to Javascript in struts 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, struts2, iterator

I have a dynamic table in Struts 2. In which I want to pass the iterator index value to a Javascript function. How can I do that? I've given the code below.

This is my table :

```
<table class="tblborder" id="priorIncident">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="gray">
                <th colspan="5" align="center"><s:text name="priorIncidentTab" /></th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="black">
                <th><s:text name="date" /></th>
                <th><s:text name="reason" /></th>
                <th><s:text name="warningInd" /></th>
                <th><s:text name="warningDate" /></th>
                <th><s:text name="warningDesc" /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="claimData.priorIncidents" var="priorIncident" status="status">
            <tr>
                <s:hidden name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].oid" />
                <td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].incidentDate" id="incidentDate1"/></td>
                <td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].incidentReason" id="incidentReason1"/></td>
                <td>
                    <s:select headerKey="" headerValue="Select" list="#{'Y':'Yes', 'N':'No'}" theme="simple" name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].hasWarning" id="hasWarning1"/>
                </td>
                <td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].warningDate" id="warningDate1"/></td>
                <td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="claimData.priorIncidents[%{#status.index}].warningDesc" id="warningDesc1"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <td><a href="#" id="add" onclick="MyFunction(%{#status.index})">Add</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a></td>
```

When I click the add link(which is not inside the iterator), I should be able to pass the  index value to some Javascript function ?
As I'm new to JS, can anybody help on this? Any answer is much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes where missing....... This must work

```
<a href="#" id="add" onclick="MyFunction('%{#status.index}')">Add</a></td>
```

if not try something like below

```
<a href="#" id="add" onclick="MyFunction('<s:property value="%{[#stat.index]}"/>')"> Add</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you're asking for.

You can initialize a JS variable with the size of the list at render time. `MyFunction` needs to *increment* that value so you can add rows, though; hardcoding the value in the function call won't work.

That means hardcoding the value in the method call won't work: you need to use a JS variable.

You could also `<s:set>` a variable in the iterator block that increments a counter, or set a variable on the last iteration, if your goal is to have a single "Add" link that starts counting at the end of the loop.

Ultimately, since you need to continually update the value as you add more items, though, simply setting a JS variable with the list size seems the best option. If you want an "Add" link for *every* item then you can use the index *inside* the iteration block.

Comment: Downvote explanations are generally appreciated. The answer pretty much sums up your options.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of the status is inside the iterator.. Use standard c tag library to set the value of status.index to a page scope variable.

```
<c:set var="foo" scope="page" value="..."/>
```

By the way, the last value of status.index is always size of the array -1 .